# Illustrator CC - New document window display error

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud

i have adobe cc in my two computers. In one of them when i open Illustrator cc, am not able to see any of the dialog selections except 'x' button. The whole window is gray as the sceenshot.

[image: new window gray box]

However i can open any older file and edit it.

My pc has 24Gb ram and intel i5-3350p.
I never had problem before. I also uninstalled and re installed the setup of creative cloud app.

---

Problem solved uninstalling avast antivirus.

Comment: Are there any software updates you need to run on the computer where this is happening? I've had some buggy experiences with CC when I'm not up to date with the latest version of my operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to Illustrator CC > Preferences > General and select the option **Use Legacy "File New" interface:**

[image]

This should revert back to the 'new file' menu from previous versions of Illustrator and work properly.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thank you for the link. You were right.